# Mobile Broadband worked in 13.04 not working in 13.10

Tags: 13.10

Does anyone know why a Sierra Wireless USB mobile broadband modem would work perfectly in 13.04 but then stop working immediately after upgrading to 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

Download the package modemmanager0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1 from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1/+build/3267777/+files/modemmanager_0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) or from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/0.5.1.97-0ubuntu1/+build/3267777).

Open `Synaptic Package Manager` type in your password when required, search for the package named `modemmanager` when you find it, hit the right click on it and hit on `Mark for complete removal` and close the `Synaptic Package Manager`.

Look for the file you downloaded before and execute it (it will may be open on the `Ubuntu Software Center`), install it and close the `Ubuntu Software Center`.

Now open one more time the `Synaptic Package Manager` and search for the package named `modemmanager` again, when you find it click on it and go to the upper menu option `Package`, hit on `Lock Version` until you see a checkmark next to that option and a locker next to the package name.

Restart your system and let us now if that worked.